# HTML5 input range styling before

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently styling HTML5 input type range  using below code:

```
input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #024069;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}


input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    -moz-apperance:none; 
    width:25px; 
    height:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px; 
    -moz-border-radius:20px; 
    -ms-border-radius:20px; 
    -o-border-radius:20px; 
    border-radius:20px;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fefefe), color-stop(0.49, #d7d7d7), color-stop(0.51, #d1d1d1), color-stop(1, #c8c8c8) );
    border: 1px solid #787878;
}
```

This is all good. But now I'm trying to have two different colours on the actual slider so left of the thumb is blue and right of the thumb is black.

I tried :before but it didn't work. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Can't be done purely with CSS i'm afraid..

Comment: Can this be done with javascript then?

Comment: @techfoobar is right, the actual slider is a single element. You can check it by enabling Shadow DOM in `chrome://flags` in Chrome. You could use JS to colour it but you would have to update the style after each change.

Comment: @techfoobar That's not correct, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13913829/1250044).

Comment: @yckart - Your solution indeed colors the bar. But what happens when i slide left or right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's some JavaScript that updates the colour of the bar when you change the value.

```js
input.oninput = function () {
  var value = (input.value - input.min)/(input.max - input.min);
  input.style.backgroundImage = [
    '-webkit-gradient(',
      'linear, ',
      'left top, ',
      'right top, ',
      'color-stop(' + value + ', blue), ',
      'color-stop(' + value + ', red)',
    ')'
  ].join('');
};
```

```js
onload = function() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    input = inputs[i]
    input.oninput = function () {
      var value = (input.value - input.min)/(input.max - input.min);
      input.style.backgroundImage = [
        '-webkit-gradient(',
          'linear, ',
          'left top, ',
          'right top, ',
          'color-stop(' + value + ', blue), ',
          'color-stop(' + value + ', red)',
        ')'
      ].join('');
    };
  }
};
```

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
}
input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperance: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 8px;
    padding: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid blue;
    border-right: 20px solid red;
    background: #024069;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.2, blue),
        color-stop(0.2, red)
    );
    outline: none;
}


input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    -moz-apperance:none; 
    width:25px; 
    height:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px; 
    -moz-border-radius:20px; 
    -ms-border-radius:20px; 
    -o-border-radius:20px; 
    border-radius:20px;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fefefe), color-stop(0.49, #d7d7d7), color-stop(0.51, #d1d1d1), color-stop(1, #c8c8c8) );
    border: 1px solid #787878;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="20">
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks to @adamvert for suggesting to use `oninput` instead of `onchange`.

Comment: Very nice, but you need to use oninput instead of onchange so that the background updates as you drag the thumb

Comment: could you provide React version of this on codesandbox ? here similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71751563/making-input-thumb-bigger-than-rest/71765592#71765592

Answer (score 2):

You'll need JS to do this the way you need. I assume you need the bar-coloring to work correctly even when you slide the thing. i.e. blue to the left and black to the right of the thumb.

Check this demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tv3bx/2/

Code:

```
function colorTheBar(slider) {
    var left = $('.left'), right = $('.right');
    console.log(slider.val());
    if(left.length == 0) {
        left = $('<div>').addClass('left').appendTo('body');
        right = $('<div>').addClass('right').appendTo('body');
    }
    left.css({
        left: (slider.offset().left + 20) + 'px',
        top: slider.offset().top + 'px',
        width: (slider.width() * (parseInt(slider.val())/100)) + 'px',
        height: slider.height() + 'px'
    });
    right.css({
        left: (slider.offset().left + 20 + slider.width() * (parseInt(slider.val())/100)) + 'px',
        top: slider.offset().top + 'px',
        width: (slider.width() * (1 - parseInt(slider.val())/100)) + 'px',
        height: slider.height() + 'px'
    });
}

$('input').change(function() {
    colorTheBar($(this));
});

colorTheBar($('input'));
​


/* CSS */

.left, .right {
    position: absolute;    
    z-index: 1;
}
.left {
    background-color: blue;
}
.right {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way do that is to use gradients:

**CSS**

```
input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #0000ff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 50%, #000000 50%, #000000 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#0000ff), color-stop(50%,#0000ff), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#000000));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #0000ff 0%,#0000ff 50%,#000000 50%,#000000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #0000ff 0%,#0000ff 50%,#000000 50%,#000000 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #0000ff 0%,#0000ff 50%,#000000 50%,#000000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #0000ff 0%,#0000ff 50%,#000000 50%,#000000 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0000ff', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 );
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}


input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    -moz-apperance:none; 
    width:25px; 
    height:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px; 
    -moz-border-radius:20px; 
    -ms-border-radius:20px; 
    -o-border-radius:20px; 
    border-radius:20px;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fefefe), color-stop(0.49, #d7d7d7), color-stop(0.51, #d1d1d1), color-stop(1, #c8c8c8) );
    border: 1px solid #787878;
}
```

To customize the gradient i recommend [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

**[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t5eFE/)**

Comment: I believe the OP wants to color the slider bar (blue to the left of the thumb and black to the right), not the slider thumb itself.

Comment: Should I use javascript to dynamically change the color on thumb change as I want blue on left and black on right of the thumb at all times??

Comment: This solution indeed colors the bar. But what happens when i slide left or right?