# Styling input range for webkit with pure CSS

Tags: css, html, pseudo-element, input-type-range

I would like to customize input type range like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV5Eb.png).

[image]

I tried to use the following code to change the thumb and as below but selected range color is not changed.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="range" />
```

**CSS**:

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Could anybody please suggest me to change the selected runnable track background color?

Comment: A pure CSS solution can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38163892 In particular, it uses box-shadow to emulate the split in colors on the track in Chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interesting approach being used by the Ionic framework for styling the range input track with just CSS. They are adding a `::before` pseudo-element to the `::-webkit-slider-thumb`, making it as wide as possible and then positioning it on top of the track. (*I couldn't get `border-radius` to work with it*.)

```css
input[type='range'] {
  width: 210px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #AAA;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: steelblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 10px; /* equal to height of runnable track */
  width: 500px; /* make this bigger than the widest range input element */
  left: -502px; /* this should be -2px - width */
  top: 8px; /* don't change this */
  background: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="10" />
</div>
```

---

<strike>As far as I am aware there is no pure CSS way to do this for Webkit powered browsers (and FF)</strike>. IE provides a way to style the two portions of the track using `-ms-fill-lower` and `-ms-fill-upper` but there are no equivalents in WebKit and hence JavaScript will be needed.

You could use a `linear-gradient` as background image for the runnable track and then change the `background-size` using JavaScript to achieve the required effect. As question is specific to Webkit, the snippet provided **currently works only in Webkit powered browsers**. This method does allow us to add a `border-radius` to the track.

This snippet was adapted from Ana Tudor's [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/gPXOJg?editors=001). That demo has ways to make it work in other browsers also.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[type=range]'),
    style_el = document.createElement('style'),
    styles = [],
    track_sel = ['::-webkit-slider-runnable-track'];
  document.body.appendChild(style_el);

  styles.push('');

  input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var min = this.min || 0,
      max = this.max || 100,
      c_style, u, edge_w, val, str = '';

    this.setAttribute('value', this.value);

    val = this.value + '% 100%';
    str += 'input[type="range"]' + track_sel[0] + '{background-size:' + val + '}';

    styles[0] = str;
    style_el.textContent = styles.join('');
  }, false);
}
```

```css
input[type='range'] {
  width: 210px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #777, #777), #AAA;
  background-size: 10% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: steelblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="10" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes using JS we have a multiple way. simplest one is calling $('input:range').css('background', 'linear-gradient(to right, red, #005555 ' +val + '%, blue)') with oninput method. But i need to do this with CSS only. Like input::-webkit-slider-thumb:after and before methods

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't note the *pure CSS* bit in the title. But there is not a way to do this with pure CSS for Webkit powered browsers. IE, I think has an upper and a lower to style the two portions of the track but Webkit (and FF) doesn't have that.

Comment: have you checked ionic range control: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#range. It has been implemented only through CSS

Comment: @Ponmalar: I will have a look at it but I guess they must be using JS (for cross browser). You may want to have a look at this article also - http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-range-slider-style/

Comment: @Ponmalar: Interesting but yes Ionic is using pure CSS and I've added it to the answer now. Thanks for that link, that's something new I learnt today :)

Comment: Why this is not working with safari browser? just run this code snippet in Safari, you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Ponmalar: I don't have Safari so can't test with it but the properties that are added are not browser specific, the selectors are browser specific but since Safari uses WebKit I assume there should be no problems with it either (but based on your comment, it seems like there is).

Answer (score 8):

I got a solution that does not use a style tag but [css variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties):

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");

function setBackgroundSize(input) {
  input.style.setProperty("--background-size", `${getBackgroundSize(input)}%`);
}

setBackgroundSize(input);

input.addEventListener("input", () => setBackgroundSize(input));

function getBackgroundSize(input) {
  const min = +input.min || 0;
  const max = +input.max || 100;
  const value = +input.value;

  const size = (value - min) / (max - min) * 100;

  return size;
}
```

```css
input[type='range'] {
  width: 400px;
}

input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #293043, #293043), #D7D7D7;
  background-size: var(--background-size, 0%) 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #293043;
  border: solid white 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/** FF*/

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: #293043;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: #D7D7D7;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #293043;
  border: solid white 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="5" max="95" step="1" value="15">
```

This works on Chrome and Firefox :).