# css3 - styling input range background

Tags: html, css, range

I need to style my input range, according to this image:
[image]

I managed to do that with the help of range.scss mixin but the problem I have is, how I can style the background when the step isn't reached.
Everything from 0 to step 75 should be green, the rest grey.

I only found some options for the complete background and not just for the already dragged steps. Any ideas?

Comment: and where exactly is your code?

Comment: sorry, adding it right now!

Comment: Maybe this would help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850327/styling-input-range-for-webkit-with-pure-css/34850882#34850882 (that is webkit only and so I'm not closing as a dupe).

Comment: There are a number of articles about this on the internet. Here's one a simple search on your title found, on this site even: [How to customize the HTML5 input range type looks using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21211386/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the line that range is on is called track, Css tricks has a detailed article on how to customize the range input.

Here is the link : https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

hope this helps.