# Align <svg><rect> on an <input>

Tags: css, html

I have a bunch of `<input>` sliders, with DOM that looks something like this -

```
<div>
  <label style="width:100px">Slider A: </label>
  <input type="range" style="width:600px; height:20px;"/>
  <svg width="600px" height="20px">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="20"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I want the `svg` rectangle to highlight portion of the input, let's say starting at left, ending exactly at middle in this example, but other ranges are also possible.

How do I do position the `svg` so that it exactly overlaps the `input`?

Comment: Overall... I'd say you're taking the wrong approach. See the fiddle provided by Ales in the *comments* [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18389801/1860561). IF  you need to use a SVG, you may need to use relative/absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this after some research. Posting in case anyone comes across this.

Basically define height/width for the container div, and set style="position:absolute" for the divs that need to overlap.

Comment: don't forget to add `position: relative` on the container element, as the absolute positioned div may end up in weird places