# How to customise range type for chrome?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know of a way to apply different styles to the upper and lower tracks of a range input in  Chrome using CSS ?
    [Something similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cih7x.png)

```
 input[type=range]::-webkit-fill-lower {
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 0.2px solid #ff0000;
   }

input[type=range]::-webkit-fill-upper {
  background: #bfbfbf;

   }

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-fill-lower {
  background: #ff0000;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-fill-upper {
  background: #bfbfbf;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38163892/3971928