# Is there a way to color the left side of a range input in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code to change the style of a slider, but so far I can't find the way to change the left side:

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 2px; 
  background: #ffffff; 
  outline: none; 
  opacity: 0.7; 
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s; 
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input
    type="range"
    min="1"
    max="100"
    value="50"
    class="slider"
    id="myRange"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style HTML5 range input to have different color before and after slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style input range background before thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771735/style-input-range-background-before-thumb). This is exactly answer here.

Comment: i tried those two before i post the question and it's just changing the background of the slider not only the left side

Comment: The examples in those answers all work. If they don't work for you, then you are doing something wrong and you'll need to post the code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [background: linear-gradient(...);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) with an [onchange JS event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)

```js
document.querySelector('.slidecontainer > input').onchange = function(e){
  this.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, red, red ' + this.value + '%, yellow ' + this.value + '%)';
};
```

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 2px; 
  background:
      linear-gradient(
          to right, 
          red,
          red 50%,
          yellow 50%
      ); 
  outline: none; 
  opacity: 0.7; 
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s; 
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input
    type="range"
    min="1"
    max="100"
    value="50"
    class="slider"
    id="myRange"
  />
</div>
```