# How to change color for a slider runnable track in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, css-selectors

I have to change the color of track ie it will be in one color before it slides and another color after sliding. It is working fine for Firefox and for Chrome it is not working. I am also facing issue with top for pointer (class) in css, it takes different for both browsers.

CSS:

```
body {

  color: red;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

header {

  background-color: white;  
  padding: 60px 40px;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 200%;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

p {
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

article {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
}

/**
 * Text Slider Directive - CSS  
 **/
.text-size-slider {
  line-height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.text-size-slider .small-letter,.text-size-slider .big-letter
{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-size-slider .slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.text-size-slider .slider:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
 content:"YEAH";
 display:block;
 background:rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 position:absolute;
 top:-20px;
 left:-10px;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-moz-range-thumb::before {
 content:"YEAH";
 display:block;
 background:rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 position:absolute;
 top:-20px;
 left:-10px;
}

.pointer {
    vertical-align:top;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius:20px 20px  0 20px;
  background-color:rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
  display:block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position:absolute;
  top: -46px;
  margin-left:13px;

  color:black;

}

.pointer span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-left:12px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  color:white;


}

.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
  border: 0;
}

.text-size-slider .slider::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
   background-color: grey;
  border: 0;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1); 
}
.text-size-slider .slider::--webkit-slider-runnable-progress {
  background-color: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1); 
}
```

Here is my plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/ecU8KvlO2jWGWy4jVAcS?p=preview

Comment: I don't see any color change in Firefox as well.

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa  No,the track color is changing,intially it is in grey color,when it slides it will be in pink color.

Comment: Regarding the difference in top position, its a common issue and for FF you need to use this `@-moz-document url-prefix() { .pointer { top: -46px; } }` rule

Comment: Regarding the color of the runable track, you could refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa yes I tried,but iam not getting.

Comment: Since the shadow DOM of the input range cannot be accessed using Firefox, I can't even check how it works there.