# how to change the color of track for range slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have to change the track color of range slider,I tried with css but in chrome it is not working,At last I find a solution using jquery([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider)),So I implemented,but I am not getting expected output.

Jquery:

```
$('.text-size-slider .slider').change(function () {
      var val = ($(this).val() - $(this).attr('min')) / ($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min'));

      $(this).css('background-image',
                  '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, '
                  + 'color-stop(' + val + ', #94A14E), '
                  + 'color-stop(' + val + ', #C5C5C5)'
                  + ')'
                  );
  });
```

Here is my plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/yMg8bKSrbam6RmtgdBl4?p=preview

Is it possible with pure javascript or angularjs without using jquery,for jquery also it is not working  as shown in plunker.

Expected output:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Please any one help me.I tried alot but unable to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your directive, you can check in this plunker

```
"https://plnkr.co/edit/UPh0guqcXxO6ivSljh8R?p=preview"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,but here is some problem,ie., Iam setting the default value(18) on load,but color is not up to the value.Can you help me in this?

Comment: Is it possible with angularjs?

Comment: I didn't get you, we are already using angular to acheive this.

Comment: But If,I removed the jquery script means it is not working

Comment: Which jquery script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143939/discussion-between-raj-and-pbsbr).

Comment: @pbsbr I have updated the plunkr without using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Replace style.css

```
body {

  color: red;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

header {

  background-color: white;  
  padding: 60px 40px;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 200%;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

p {
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

article {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
}

/**
 * Text Slider Directive - CSS  
 **/
.text-size-slider {
  line-height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.text-size-slider .small-letter,.text-size-slider .big-letter
{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-size-slider .slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0px 8px;
}

.text-size-slider .slider:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
 content:"YEAH";
 display:block;
 background:red !important;
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 position:absolute;
 top:-20px;
 left:-10px;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb::after {
 content:"YEAH";
 display:block;
 background:green !important;
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 position:absolute;
 top:-20px;
 left:-10px;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-moz-range-thumb::before {
 content:"YEAH";
 display:block;
 background:rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 position:absolute;
 top:-20px;
 left:-10px;
}

.pointer {
    vertical-align:top;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius:20px 20px  0 20px;
  background-color:rgba(192, 35, 74, 1);
  display:block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position:absolute;
  top: -39px;
  margin-left:14px;

  color:black;

}

.pointer span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-left:12px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  color:white;


}

.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;

  border: 0;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: yellow;
  border: 0;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #ddd;
  border: 0;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1); 
  height: 2px;
}
.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: orange;
}{
  background-color: rgba(192, 35, 74, 1); 
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() { .pointer { top: -40px; } }

 .text-size-slider .slider::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .text-size-slider .slider::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
 .text-size-slider .slider{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperance: none;
    /*! border-radius: 6px; */
    height: 0px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.15, #ddd), color-stop(0.15, #ddd) );
}

.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry,I need two colors for the track before and after the thumb.

Comment: can you put image? exactly you want

Comment: I updated the image in question,can you please check it once,that was the result am expecting.

Comment: please also check 
https://plnkr.co/edit/50XVxiRZwwdjvekAC0N0?p=preview