# Create range input with progress bar CSS

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I'm trying to create range input with progress bar.
I've found this solution

```css
input {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 240px;
}

input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #e33d44;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 18px;
  width: 28px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 6px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 7px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 8px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 9px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 10px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 11px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 12px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 13px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 14px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 15px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 16px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 17px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 18px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 19px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 20px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 21px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 22px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 23px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 24px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 25px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 26px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 27px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 28px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 29px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 30px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 31px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 32px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 33px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 34px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 35px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 36px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 37px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 38px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 39px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 40px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 41px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 42px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 43px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 44px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 45px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 46px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 47px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 48px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 49px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 50px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 51px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 52px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 53px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 54px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 55px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 56px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 57px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 58px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 59px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 60px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 61px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 62px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 63px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 64px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 65px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 66px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 67px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 68px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 69px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 70px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 71px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 72px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 73px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 74px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 75px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 76px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 77px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 78px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 79px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 80px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 81px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 82px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 83px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 84px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 85px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 86px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 87px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 88px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 89px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 90px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 91px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 92px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 93px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 94px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 95px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 96px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 97px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 98px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 99px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 100px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 101px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 102px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 103px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 104px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 105px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 106px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 107px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 108px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 109px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 110px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 111px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 112px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 113px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 114px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 115px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 116px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 117px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 118px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 119px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 120px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 121px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 122px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 123px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 124px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 125px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 126px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 127px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 128px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 129px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 130px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 131px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 132px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 133px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 134px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 135px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 136px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 137px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 138px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 139px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 140px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 141px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 142px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 143px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 144px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 145px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 146px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 147px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 148px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 149px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 150px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 151px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 152px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 153px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 154px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 155px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 156px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 157px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 158px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 159px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 160px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 161px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 162px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 163px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 164px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 165px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 166px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 167px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 168px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 169px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 170px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 171px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 172px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 173px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 174px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 175px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 176px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 177px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 178px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 179px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 180px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 181px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 182px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 183px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 184px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 185px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 186px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 187px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 188px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 189px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 190px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 191px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 192px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 193px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 194px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 195px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 196px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 197px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 198px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 199px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 200px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 201px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 202px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 203px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 204px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 205px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 206px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 207px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 208px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 209px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 210px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 211px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 212px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 213px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 214px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 215px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 216px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 217px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 218px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 219px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 220px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 221px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 222px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 223px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 224px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 225px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 226px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 227px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 228px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 229px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 230px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 231px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 232px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 233px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 234px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 235px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 236px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 237px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 238px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 239px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7, 240px 0 0 -8px #c7c7c7;
  margin-top: -8px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

input::-moz-range-track {
  width: 240px;
  height: 2px;
}

input::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 18px;
  width: 28px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: relative;
}

input::-moz-range-progress {
  height: 2px;
  background: #e33d44;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

input::-ms-track {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  color: transparent;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 240px;
}

input::-ms-thumb {
  height: 18px;
  width: 28px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

input::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #e33d44;
  border-radius: 0;
}

input::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: 0;
}

input::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="40" />
```

but if we change the width of input to 640px - red progress bar working incorrect. Progress bar works with help property - box-shadow. As you can see the value of this property too big and I've no idea how to manipulate with this. Can you help me with this property? May be special services for generating advanced box-shadow?

Comment: this solution might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/38163892/4858751

Comment: My word is do not involve with this, i recommend you use `jquery UI` slider instead.

Answer (score 7):

well, i found a solution for you with using `gradient` instead of `box-shadow` and you can control width of progress bar with `background-size` check out this demo:

```js
$('input[type=range]').on('input', function(e){
  var min = e.target.min,
      max = e.target.max,
      val = e.target.value;
  
  $(e.target).css({
    'backgroundSize': (val - min) * 100 / (max - min) + '% 100%'
  });
}).trigger('input');
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=range] {
    margin: auto;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 640px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #ff1100), color-stop(100%, #ff1100));
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}


input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 18px;
  width: 28px;
    border: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="40" />
```

Comment: Nice solution. I modified it a bit and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is easily achieved, though with a bit of javascript.
Use this tool: https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler

```js
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"].slider-progress')) {
  e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value);
  e.style.setProperty('--min', e.min == '' ? '0' : e.min);
  e.style.setProperty('--max', e.max == '' ? '100' : e.max);
  e.addEventListener('input', () => e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value));
}
```

```css
/*generated with Input range slider CSS style generator (version 20201223)
https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler*/
input[type=range].styled-slider {
  height: 2.2em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*progress support*/
input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress {
  --range: calc(var(--max) - var(--min));
  --ratio: calc((var(--value) - var(--min)) / var(--range));
  --sx: calc(0.5 * 2em + var(--ratio) * (100% - 2em));
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/*webkit*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  margin-top: calc(max((1em - 1px - 1px) * 0.5,0px) - 2em * 0.5);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
}
input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #0061c3;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  background: #2f98f9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#007cf8,#007cf8) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #efefef;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#0061c3,#0061c3) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #e5e5e5;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#2f98f9,#2f98f9) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #f5f5f5;
}

/*mozilla*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-track {
  height: max(calc(1em - 1px - 1px),0px);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #0061c3;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-moz-range-track {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb:active {
  background: #2f98f9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-moz-range-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#007cf8,#007cf8) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #efefef;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#0061c3,#0061c3) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #e5e5e5;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#2f98f9,#2f98f9) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #f5f5f5;
}

/*ms*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb:hover {
  background: #0061c3;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-ms-track {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb:active {
  background: #2f98f9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-ms-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-ms-fill-lower {
  height: max(calc(1em - 1px - 1px),0px);
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
  margin: -1px 0 -1px -1px;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #0061c3;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2f98f9;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="styled-slider slider-progress" style="width: 25em;" />
```