# Also changing the gradient of customized slider through reset button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
//Start FOnt Size Slider
function isOlderEdgeOrIE() {
  return (
    window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 ||
    !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./) ||
    window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1
  );
}

function valueTotalRatio(value, min, max) {
  return ((value - min) / (max - min)).toFixed(2);
}

function getLinearGradientCSS(ratio, leftColor, rightColor) {
  return [
    '-webkit-gradient(',
    'linear, ',
    'left top, ',
    'right top, ',
    'color-stop(' + ratio + ', ' + leftColor + '), ',
    'color-stop(' + ratio + ', ' + rightColor + ')',
    ')'
  ].join('');
}

function updateRangeEl(rangeEl) {
  var ratio = valueTotalRatio(rangeEl.value, rangeEl.min, rangeEl.max);

  rangeEl.style.backgroundImage = getLinearGradientCSS(ratio, '#8e2f58', '#c5c5c5');
}

function initRangeEl() {
  var rangeEl = document.querySelector('input[type=range]');
  var textEl = document.querySelector('.fntSz');

  /**
   * IE/Older Edge FIX
   * On IE/Older Edge the height of the <input type="range" />
   * is the whole element as oposed to Chrome/Moz
   * where the height is applied to the track.
   *
   */
  if (isOlderEdgeOrIE()) {
    rangeEl.style.height = "20px";
    // IE 11/10 fires change instead of input
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/50887531/3528132
    rangeEl.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      textEl.value = e.target.value;
    });
    rangeEl.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      textEl.value = e.target.value;
    });
  } else {
    updateRangeEl(rangeEl);
    rangeEl.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      updateRangeEl(e.target);
      textEl.value = e.target.value;
    });
  }
}

initRangeEl();
//End Font Size Slider



$('.resetbtn').click(function(){
      $('#slider, .fntSz').val(40);
});
```

```css
/*Start Font Size Slilder*/
.fntSz{
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: initial;
  color: #757575;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Chrome thumb*/

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /*16x16px adjusted to be same as 14x14px on moz*/
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8e2f58;
}


/*Mozilla thumb*/

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8e2f58;
}


/*IE & Edge input*/

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 6px;
  /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
  background: transparent;
  /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 2px 0;
  /*remove default tick marks*/
  color: transparent;
}


/*IE & Edge thumb*/

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8e2f58;
}


/*IE & Edge left side*/

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #8e2f58;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/*IE & Edge right side*/

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #8e2f58;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/*IE disable tooltip*/

input[type=range]::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
}
/*End Font Size Slilder*/
```

```html
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <input type="range" value="40" min="10" max="100" step="1" id="slider" />
        <button type="button" name="button" class="resetbtn" value="Reset form"> Reset </button>
```

Hello, Here I use a slider, a customized slider where I use two-color before pointer and after pointer then I create a reset button which reset the value of the input(slider input) and it works well also but the problem is with color when we click on reset button color did not reset. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `initRangeEl();` again when clicking the reset button to let it re-draw the style of the element based on the slider value.

```
$('.resetbtn').click(function(){
   $('#slider, .fntSz').val(40);
   initRangeEl();
});
```

```js
//Start FOnt Size Slider
function isOlderEdgeOrIE() {
  return (
    window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 ||
    !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./) ||
    window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1
  );
}

function valueTotalRatio(value, min, max) {
  return ((value - min) / (max - min)).toFixed(2);
}

function getLinearGradientCSS(ratio, leftColor, rightColor) {
  return [
    '-webkit-gradient(',
    'linear, ',
    'left top, ',
    'right top, ',
    'color-stop(' + ratio + ', ' + leftColor + '), ',
    'color-stop(' + ratio + ', ' + rightColor + ')',
    ')'
  ].join('');
}

function updateRangeEl(rangeEl) {
  var ratio = valueTotalRatio(rangeEl.value, rangeEl.min, rangeEl.max);

  rangeEl.style.backgroundImage = getLinearGradientCSS(ratio, '#8e2f58', '#c5c5c5');
}

function initRangeEl() {
  var rangeEl = document.querySelector('input[type=range]');
  var textEl = document.querySelector('.fntSz');

  /**
   * IE/Older Edge FIX
   * On IE/Older Edge the height of the <input type="range" />
   * is the whole element as oposed to Chrome/Moz
   * where the height is applied to the track.
   *
   */
  if (isOlderEdgeOrIE()) {
    rangeEl.style.height = "20px";
    // IE 11/10 fires change instead of input
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/50887531/3528132
    rangeEl.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      textEl.value = e.target.value;
    });
    rangeEl.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      textEl.value = e.target.value;
    });
  } else {
    updateRangeEl(rangeEl);
    rangeEl.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      updateRangeEl(e.target);
      textEl.value = e.target.value;
    });
  }
}

initRangeEl();
//End Font Size Slider



$('.resetbtn').click(function(){
      $('#slider, .fntSz').val(40);
      initRangeEl();
});
```

```css
/*Start Font Size Slilder*/
.fntSz{
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: initial;
  color: #757575;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Chrome thumb*/

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /*16x16px adjusted to be same as 14x14px on moz*/
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8e2f58;
}


/*Mozilla thumb*/

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8e2f58;
}


/*IE & Edge input*/

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 6px;
  /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
  background: transparent;
  /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 2px 0;
  /*remove default tick marks*/
  color: transparent;
}


/*IE & Edge thumb*/

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8e2f58;
}


/*IE & Edge left side*/

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #8e2f58;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/*IE & Edge right side*/

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #8e2f58;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/*IE disable tooltip*/

input[type=range]::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
}
/*End Font Size Slilder*/
```

```html
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <input type="range" value="40" min="10" max="100" step="1" id="slider" />
        <button type="button" name="button" class="resetbtn" value="Reset form"> Reset </button>
```