# StencilJS component with shadow dom enabled does not generate the helper CSS classes for dynamically added elements on IE11/Edge

Tags: ionic-framework, internet-explorer-11, web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I've created a new project using the stencil component starter. Inside my component I'm using an external JS [nouislider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/), which injects HTML elements into my `div` (`this.slider` ref):

```js
...
componentDidLoad() {
  noUiSlider.create(this.slider, {
    start: [20, 80],
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    }
  })
}
...
```

I've copied the slider's CSS into `my-component.css` and rewrote everything with `:host` selectors for the shadow dom:

```css
:host(.my-component) .noUi-target {
    position: relative;
    direction: ltr
}
```

Everything works fine on Chrome/Firefox but the slider styles are not working on IE11/Edge because Stencil appends a helper `sc-my-component` class to every element that I have inside the render method and generates CSS rules like so:

```css
.my-component.sc-my-component-h .noUi-target.sc-my-component {
  position: relative;
  direction: ltr
}
```

but the injected `nouislider` child HTML elements don't have the helper classes on them. I have an ugly fix for this case atm:

```js
...
componentDidLoad() {
  noUiSlider.create(this.slider, {
    start: [20, 80],
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    }
  })
  this.slider.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((child)=>{
    child.classList.add('sc-my-component')
  })
}
...
```

I'm appending the helper classes after the slider is created (the slider generates child `divs` only). Is there a better way to tell Stencil that I'm injecting elements inside lifecycle methods and that it needs to recognize those elements when CSS rules are being generated?

Comment: From the [browser suppot page](https://stenciljs.com/docs/browser-support) of Stencil, it seems that we need polyfills to support Shadow Dom in IE and Edge. You could refer to [this page](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil#internet-explorer-11) about adding polyfills for IE 11 and adding [Custom Elements v1](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/custom-elements) polyfill for Edge to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, nevertheless this could also be interesting for you:

We are currently working on the same topic (StencilJS, shadow: true, noUiSlider) and encountered the problem, that the slider's touch events are not working correctly in shadowDOM on mobile devices. We found a solution for this and already created a PR (https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/pull/1060).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the PR! I also had a problem with this, so for now I ended up using the [native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60560815/3528132) `<input type="range" />` and making it compatible for all the browsers that Stencil supports. Works for my case, I only needed a simple slider with min, max and step values.

Answer (score 0):

I too had problems using nouislider in StencilJS but just managed to make it work.

my-slider.scss

```
 @import '~nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css';

 :host {
     padding: 50px 30px;
     display: block;
 }
```

my-slider.tsx

```
import { Component, h, Prop, Event, EventEmitter } from '@stencil/core';
import noUiSlider from "nouislider";


@Component({
    tag: 'skim-slider',
    styleUrl: 'skim-slider.scss',
    shadow: true
})
export class SkimSlider {

    @Prop() min!: number;
    @Prop() max!: number;

    private slider: HTMLElement;

    @Event() update: EventEmitter;

    componentDidLoad() {
        const slider = noUiSlider.create(this.slider, {
            start: [this.min, this.max],
            tooltips: [true, true],
            range: {
                'min': this.min,
                'max': this.max
            }
        });
        slider.on('change', (value) => this.update.emit(value));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={e => this.slider = e}></div>
        );
    }
}
```

The trick that did it for me was 'display: block'

Comment: I don't see how `display: block;` solves the problem of adding the scope class name to dynamically created elements...