# Track Color in input type Range in react

Tags: reactjs

I have the next input type range in react:

```
    inputElement = <div className={styles.InputElementRange}>                
     <input
        min={props.min}
        max={props.min}
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.changed}
    ></input>
    <input 
       type="text"
       value={props.value}
       onChange={props.changed}
       style={props.stylesElement}              
     />             
   </div>
```

and I got this:

[image]

The input type range works very well but I couldn't change the styles of the track.

How can I change the  blue color by default? I want to replace the blue color for orange color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to share the styles for `styles.InputElementRange` otherwise it's difficult to know what you have tried specifically to change the styles.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
inputElement = <div className={styles.InputElementRange}>                
     <input
        min={props.min}
        max={props.min}
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.changed}
        style={{'background': `linear-gradient(to right, orange ${(parseInt(props.value)-props.min)*100/(props.max-props.min)}%, #ccc 0px`}}
    ></input>
    <input 
       type="text"
       value={props.value}
       onChange={props.changed}
       style={props.stylesElement}              
     />             
   </div>
```

and these are the styles:

```
input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: orange;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  /* All the same stuff for IE */
  input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

I thought my answer based in this answer:  [`Ver link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider/57153340#57153340)

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/) to see how you can style the HTML slider

Comment: I saw this code and I tested, but these styles put the same color to the filled bar and unfilled bar.

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/38163892/3161811 maybe that will help you, I didn't test it though

Comment: I don't know how to adapt the js code to react.  I'm going to check how to do it.

Comment: The answer I referred to is CSS only.

Comment: I'm gonna check it .  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm going to share another solution using react and the styles given in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy one pretty straight forward.
Note that I'm using styled components but you can use the same with vanilla css or sass as well

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Slider = () => {
  const [bgSize, setBgSize] = useState(0)

  const handleSlide = (e) => {
    setBgSize(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <SliderContainer>
      <ColorSlider
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleSlide(e)
        }}
        bgSize={bgSize}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        type={'range'}
      />
    </SliderContainer>
  )
}

export const SliderContainer = styled.div``

export const ColorSlider = styled.input`
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default CSS styles */
  appearance: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff4500, #ff4500);
  background-size: ${({ bgSize }) => bgSize}% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid;

  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    // position: relative;
    appearance: none;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #4d4945;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    outline: none;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: transparent;
  }
`
```