# Custom value Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[Value slider - Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peS0n.png)

I have a problem with replicating the exact design of the above mentioned slider and the slider value is from **1 to 5**. At this moment I need to add colors according to the value of the slider.

*Color conditions:*

Default - **Gray**, Once dragged and up to 3 - **Green**, Above 3 to 4 - **Orange**, Above 4 to 5 - **red**.

I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this resolve your issue? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider