# how to change the react-bootsrap-range-slider color?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, slider, react-bootstrap

```
return (
        <div style={divStyles}>
            <Row style={{"justifyContent": "center"}}>
                <Col xs={2}>
                    { title }
                </Col>
                <Col xs={2}>
                    <RangeSlider variant="primary" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(+e.target.value)} min={minLimit} max={maxLimit}></RangeSlider>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={1}>
                    <TextField
                            label={title} variant="standard"
                            value={ value }
                            type="number"
                            onChange={e => setValueWithLimit(+e.target.value)}
                        />
                </Col>
                <Col xs={2}>
                    { renderDays() }
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
```

The above code is a slider component, used for multiple actions, I spent the past three hours in trying to figure out how to change the slider color, which is blue right now, to a different color.

one way of doing it is by changing variants, but, none of them have me designated color.

Comment: maybe with pure css? can you add a codesandbox?

Comment: apparently i cannot, project is on gitLab and not github

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style HTML5 range input to have different color before and after slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use pure css solution, then using this will override the color of the circle of the slider

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: red !important;
}

/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: red !important;
}

/* All the same stuff for IE */
input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  background: red !important;
}
```