# How can I change range bar cursor color?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How can I change range bar cursor color?
[image]

My code is

```
              <input className="range-input" type="range" name="speed" min="0" max="100" 
              value={brightness_value} onChange={handleSliderChange}></input>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57153340/15351296

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of the cursor like this :

```
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  background: // your color;
}
```

Check this website : [Style input range](https://www.cssportal.com/style-input-range/), you will find any answers with range input.

Comment: Thanks but nothing change..