# Styling input type range as music slider

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style **input type range** for my "music app" but I cannot figure out how...
The default state without my CSS has **blue line** that shows "progress" when a song is playing and **white line** that shows how "long" the song is.

With my current CSS I've managed to just customize the thumb and change the overall color of the slider.
I am really lost here, I feel like I'm missing something really easy...

EDIT: I forgot to post the picture of how it looks/should look

[image: my slider and defalt slider]

```css
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: white;
    }

    input[type=range]{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        background: #2c2929;
    }

    input:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #music-bar{
        width: 340px;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
        height: 2.5px;
        border-radius: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
```

```html
<input type="range" id="music-bar" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="0.3">
```

Comment: you should check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider

Comment: I managed to somehow get it "working" with the link you've provided but the problem with my code is that the "white line" is not properly following the slider's thumb.
**video** [link](https://kappa.lol/Nld34)
**codepen** [link](https://codepen.io/hanzilka/pen/PoVZoLg) cant really show you properly that the slider is not moving at the same pace as the thumb but I hope you can understand the thing (I've updated the JS a bit so it will play the first audio and show that he slider is slower)