# Slider color not changing

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a custom color to my input element. The code below is filling the color throughout the slider instead of just till the value. Somebody please explain this.

```
<input
        class="w-full h-1 rounded-lg appearance-none outline-none cursor-pointer"
        type="range"
        value="60"
        min="0"
        max="100" />
```

heres the css

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 0.25rem;
  background: #c93b76;
}
```

here's the image of my code.

[image]

Comment: i think theres a misunderstanding of what ::-webkit-slider-runnable-track does...according to MDN it is the whole "track" not up to its value...[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-runnable-track)

Comment: Check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57153340/14046126

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style HTML5 range input to have different color before and after slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS you’ve provided is changing the background color of the entire track of the range input, not just the portion before the thumb (the slider’s current value).
To color only the portion of the track before the thumb, you can use the ::-webkit-slider-runnable-track pseudo-element for the track and the ::-webkit-slider-thumb pseudo-element for the thumb. Here’s an example:

```
<input
    class="w-full h-1 rounded-lg appearance-none outline-none cursor-pointer slider"
    type="range"
    value="60"
    min="0"
    max="100" />
And the CSS:
input[type='range'].slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
}

input[type='range'].slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type='range'].slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #c93b76;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

input[type='range'].slider:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type='range'].slider:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #c93b76;
}
```

This will color the track up to the thumb in #c93b76 when the slider is in focus. When the slider is not in focus, the track will be #ddd.
Please note that this solution is for Webkit browsers (like Chrome and Safari). For full cross-browser compatibility, you would need to include the equivalent code for other browsers.
Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for answering but when slider is focused its applying color to entire slider. [link](https://sakshii2000.github.io/working-on-css/04_MusicPlayer/dist/)