# making input thumb bigger than rest

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, material-ui

React developer here, trying to learn by coding, here i have a slider which im trying to make thumb bigger but it does not get bigger than input where it is(as you can see if i make thumb bigger it wont show it fully). Any advice on how to make that look like the one i want?

English is not my mother language so could be mistakes.

so here is my slider:

[image]

i want it to look like this:

[image]

what i have done already:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-architecture-s4we0m?file=/src/styles.css

css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  input[type="range"] {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80px;
    /* -webkit-appearance: none; */
    background-color: white;
  }

  input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 10px;
    /* -webkit-appearance: none; */
    color: #13bba4;
    margin-top: -1px;
  }

  input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 10px;
    /* -webkit-appearance: none; */
    height: 20px;
    cursor: ew-resize;
    background: #434343;
    box-shadow: -80px 0 0 80px #ce7c00;
  }
}
/** FF*/
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: #43e5f7;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: #9a905d;
}
/* IE*/
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: #43e5f7;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background-color: #9a905d;
}
```

js:

```
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
// Style
const MainWrapper = {
  background: "salmon",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100vh",
  position: "relative"
};

const InputWrapper = {
  position: "fixed",
  zIndex: 9999,
  width: "100%"
};

const ScaleIndicator = {
  textAlign: "right",
  position: "absolute",
  right: "40px",
  background: "blue",
  color: "white",
  zIndex: "1000",
  padding: "10px"
};

const Slider = {
  width: "200px",
  margin: "10px 30px"
};

export default function App() {
  const transformComponentRef = useRef(null);
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(0.7);

  const updateScale = (e) => {
    const targetScale = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    const factor = Math.log(targetScale / scale);
    const { zoomIn, zoomOut } = transformComponentRef.current;

    /*
      how react-zoom-pan-pinch calculate new scale :
      targetScale = scale * Math.exp(1 * factor);

      we need factor(step) for zoomIn and zoomOut, just reverse the previous equation to get factor
      factor = Math.log(targetScale / currentScale);
    */
    // console.log(scale * Math.exp(1 * factor), newScale);

    // const targetScale = scale * Math.exp(1 * factor);

    if (targetScale > scale) {
      zoomIn(factor, 0);
    } else {
      zoomOut(-factor, 0);
    }

    setScale(targetScale);
  };

  return (
    <div style={MainWrapper}>
      <h1 style={ScaleIndicator}>{(scale * 100).toFixed(0)}%</h1>
      <div style={InputWrapper}>
        <input
          type="range"
          min="0.1"
          max="1.5"
          step="0.01"
          value={scale}
          onChange={updateScale}
          style={Slider}
        />
      </div>
      <TransformWrapper
        ref={transformComponentRef}
        onZoomStop={(e) => {
          setScale(e.state.scale);
        }}
        initialScale={scale}
        minScale={0.1}
        maxScale={1.5}
        doubleClick={{
          disabled: true
        }}
        // wheel={{
        //   activationKeys: ["z"]
        // }}
        // panning={{
        //   activationKeys: ["x"],
        // }}
        limitToBounds={false}
        zoomAnimation={{ disabled: true }}
        centerOnInit
        onZoom={(e) => {
          setScale(e.state.scale);
        }}
      >
        {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, setTransform, ...rest }) => {
          return (
            <TransformComponent
              wrapperStyle={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%"
              }}
            >
              <img
                src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2450218/pexels-photo-2450218.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                alt="Cool Astro"
              />
            </TransformComponent>
          );
        }}
      </TransformWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

that link i provided looks totally different with firefox browser, idea on that also ?

Comment: any help is appreciated

Comment: I assume you got your CSS from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider/38163892#38163892) - as noted in the comments, this doesn't account for the thumb not being able to be bigger than the track due to overflow: hidden. The [other popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224#57153340) addresses this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style HTML5 range input to have different color before and after slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider)

Comment: Those are in pure javascript, could you possibly write an answer in React so that others could learn that in React and i could accept ur answr, my js is weak…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to style the `<input type="range" />` element as already pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider). If you don't care about the pure CSS solution then with React, you can simply take advantage of the input `onChange` event
to grab the input element with `e.currentTarget` and apply the necessary stylings to change the appearance mentioned in the post above

```
<input 
  onChange={(e) => {
    updateStyles(e.currentTarget);
  }}
/>
```

I'd also suggest getting familiar with the `useRef` & `useEffect` hooks, this ensures that the styles also get applied on the initial render.

Here's your modified [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-chandrasekhar-ycm667?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Slider react component. You can add some props to value, min, max, two way binding to control it from parent component and improve it. [Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-jennings-pg5nz4?file=/src/components/slider.js)

> There is a problem with thumb. In chrome if you want the thumb to be
> larger than the track, then the box shadow overlaps the track with the
> height of the thumb.
>
> Just sumup all these answers and wrote normally working slider with
> larger slider thumb.
> [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63941494)

```
const Slider = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(25);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.checked);
  };

  const initSlider = () => {
    const slider = inputRef.current;
    const min = slider.min;
    const max = slider.max;
    const value = slider.value;

    slider.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, red ${
      ((value - min) / (max - min)) * 100
    }%, #DEE2E6 ${((value - min) / (max - min)) * 100}%, #DEE2E6 100%)`;

    slider.oninput = function () {
      this.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, red ${
        ((this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)) * 100
      }%, #DEE2E6 ${
        ((this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)) * 100
      }%, #DEE2E6 100%)`;
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initSlider();
  });

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      id="slider"
      onChange={onChange}
      type="range"
      min={0}
      defaultValue={value}
      max={100}
    />
  );
};
```

P.S. Maybe, there is some mistakes, because I used to code on vue.js. I tried my best)

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try this CSS code in your slider thumb class? I think it will work :)

you can use this link as well

https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler/slider-styler.html

```
 input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      cursor: ew-resize;
      background: #434343;
      box-shadow: -100px 0 0 100px #ce7c00;
      -webkit-appearance: none;  
      border: none;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #434343;
      margin-top: -7px;
    }
```

Comment: it wont make it bigger, you can also try with that codesandbox, just paste ur css there

Comment: cool, I will try that! and will let you know what I can see :)

Answer (score -1):

For general styling of range input look at this great article [styling cross browser compatible range inputs css](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)

This covers most of the things you can do with input ranges and also author created a site to create input ranges. [range.css - generate styles for your HTML5 Inputs
by Daniel Stern](http://danielstern.ca/range.css/#/)

To be able to change the color of lower and upper part of the slider in Chrome you have to write a little bit of js code, for that you can check this thread [Style lower and upper fill in HTML5 range input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283332/style-lower-and-upper-fill-in-html5-range-input)